# Broadcasting large lookup table causes kryoserializer error

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a large RDD containing objects that is about 10GB in size. I want to convert this to a lookup table to be used in spark with the command:

`val lookupTable = sparkContext.broadcast(entitiesRDD.collect)` but it fails with:

`17/02/27 17:33:25 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, d1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 2. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value.
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I can not increase the spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max past 2048mb or I get the error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max must be less than 2048 mb, got: + 2048 mb.
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:66)`

How do other people make large lookup tables in spark?

Comment: I don't think Spark is designed for that, of course you can use something like 'filter' to extract your data, but it's not nearly as effective/convinient as using regular caches/databases